# Apache redirect causing inifinite loop

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I know this is going to be something very basic but I have wasted enough time fiddling with it now.

Got a site that is old and rubbish now so while its under going development I want all pages on it to redirect to the under_construction.htm page I made.

I have tried various versions of the below 2 rules in both my .htaccess file and my httpd.conf (I know both are being 'listened' to as I have other rules like ServerAlias / caching etc. setup and they work fine).

```
<Directory "home/xxxx/test">
        AllowOverride All
        Options None
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
</Directory>

<VirtualHost *:80>
        DocumentRoot /home/xxxx/test
        ServerName www.test.com
        ServerAlias test.com
        Redirect 301 / http://www.test.com/under_construction.htm
</VirtualHost>
```

And:-

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/under_construction.htm
RewriteRule ^ /under_construction.htm [R=301]
```

Both of these just either cause me to get an apache test page on the homepage and a 404 on all other pages (including the construction page) or it causes a browser error due to too many redirects.

Can someone correct my stupidity please!

Thanks in advance

Comment: do you want to redirect everything to under_construction.htm , am I right?

Answer (score 0):

Put the following code at the main directory .htaccess file :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule  (.*)$  path/to/under_construction.htm
```

Make sure that you write the path without starting by / and path start from the main directory for example if you are in www directory and under_construction.htm
path is like this www/folder/folder/folder/under_construction.htm
so when write it in .Htaccess write the path like this

```
RewriteRule  (.*)$  folder/folder/folder/under_construction.htm
```

No / before the path and it will work without any problem and redirect everything to under_construction.htm unless you have some Sub directorates .htaccess rules that override this .

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. If I add a new .htaccess file with nothing in it except RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule  (.*)$  under_construction.htm the homepage goes to an apache test page and all other pages 404

Comment: restart apache after making change as well as removing cockies & cache from browser and try again

Comment: Tried that :/ I restart Apache after every change and always use fresh Private browsing windows, have tried on a PC on a different external IP too. I've done this sort of thing loads of times in the past, not sure what I am missing this time!